# How do I put a bold line under certain rows in a QTabWIdget?

Tags: python, pyside6

I have a table that looks like this[image: PICTURE OF TABLE]

I am looking to set bold underlines on certain rows based on the value in the first cell in that row's values such as revenue avg 3, and tangible book ... I am stumped as where to start.

I am looking to implement a QItemDelegate to underline a whole row based on the value in the leftmost cell so 'revenue avg 3' would result in the whole line getting underlined.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QPen, QBrush
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QStyle


class TickerTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self,  parent=None, *args):
        super(TickerTableModel,  self).__init__(parent,  *args)
        self._filters = {}
        self._sortBy = []
        self._sortDirection = []
        self._dfSource = pd.DataFrame()
        self._dfDisplay = pd.DataFrame()

    def rowCount(self,  parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dfDisplay.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self,  parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dfDisplay.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return self._dfDisplay.values[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation=QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._dfDisplay.columns[col])
        return None

    def setupModel(self, data):
        self._dfSource = data
        self._sortBy = []
        self._sortDirection = []
        self.setFilters({})

    def setFilters(self, filters):
        self.modelAboutToBeReset.emit()
        self._filters = filters
        self.updateDisplay()
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def updateDisplay(self):

        dfDisplay = self._dfSource.copy()

        # Filtering
        cond = pd.Series(True, index=dfDisplay.index)
        for column, value in self._filters.items():
            cond = cond & \
                   (dfDisplay[column].str.lower().str.find(str(value).lower()) >= 0)
        dfDisplay = dfDisplay[cond]

        # Sorting
        if len(self._sortBy) != 0:
            dfDisplay.sort_values(by=self._sortBy,
                                  ascending=self._sortDirection,
                                  inplace=True)

        # Updating
        self._dfDisplay = dfDisplay


class TickerTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def setupUi(self, TickerTableWidget):
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(TickerTableWidget)
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(TickerTableWidget)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TickerTableWidget)


class TickerTableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TickerTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = TickerTableView()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.tableModel = TickerTableModel()
        self.tableModel.setupModel(data)
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel)

        # Set delegate here
        self.delegate = TickerTableDelegate(self.ui)
        self.ui.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)



class TickerTableDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None, *args):
        QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent, *args)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        # set text color
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
        text = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)

        if text:
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))

        painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignCenter, text)
        painter.restore()
```

My main.py might be something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'revenue avg 3' : [1,5,10], 'profit': [5, 4, 5], 'income': [3,5,6]})
    window = TickerTableWidget(df)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I believe the process is get the row in the item delegate, test the value in column 0 and then set some property (which) to underline the whole row (maybe underline each cell in that row). I am currently stuck on the Item Delegate doing nothing no matter what I try.

Comment: You are not using a QTableWidget, so I don't understand why you're looking into its documentation. Besides, you should only check the requirement when the `role` is a [`FontRole`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) and eventually return a proper [QFont](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfont.html) (you can construct it based on the `QApplication.font()` static function and then call `setBold()`). It seems like you are not completely understanding how Qt Model/View works, so I strongly suggest you (*again*) to take your time and read [the documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: ok, will do. Thanks. I was not talking about a fontrole though. I am talking about a style on the row itself.

Comment: Also, that while loop makes no sense: 1. using while to iterate through a continuous range of numbers is pointless (and slow), as you could just do `for row in range(self.rowCount()):`; 2. it keeps checking the *current* `index`, which will always be the same, so you should check that *before* entering any loop; 3. if you want to check if the current *row* matches a value within its items, you have to iterate through the *columns* of that row, not the rows of the model (see [`QModelIndex.siblingAtColumn()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex.html#siblingAtColumn).

Comment: Sorry, but your request was a bit confusing: I assumed you wanted to show underlined text. If you want to show a horizontal line *under the cells* of specific rows, that has nothing to do with the model (at least, not directly): item models have no direct control over the way they are actually displayed: they don't "draw" anything, the view does that; the model returns *hints* about items could be shown, it's up to the view to actually respect those hints. If you want to show a line under specific rows, then you either use an item delegate or implement it in the view's `paintEvent()`.

Comment: so i want DecorationRole

Comment: No, as the [`ItemDataRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) documentation explains, that role is for the *icon*. You can create custom roles, just use a value equal or greater than `UserRole`, then check it within the override of the `paint()` function of the item delegate. Note that, since you're using a custom model and the column names are probably known and established, as long as you're not looking in further expansibility, you could just create a custom attribute for the model that represents the row(s) that requires to be underlined.

Comment: @musicamante can you go into detail how I messed up MVC with my code please? I am stumped.

Comment: It's not messed up, but you are probably missing some aspects. What is it that you don't understand or that you cannot implement? Note that, as already suggested, if you want to implement sorting or filtering, it would be easier to do it just by using a QSortFilterProxyModel. This is *extremely* important especially for filtering: you should not just reset the model, because it would create some important issues (starting with the simple aspect of keeping consistent selections).

Comment: It appears I need to implement a QItemDelegate for this. However, I can not get the delegate to run.

Comment: I suggest you to take your time and create a valid [mre] (including basic data for the model, the contents are not relevant, it's just for the sake of the example) with your attempts to achieve what you want, so that we can understand and point out the problems within your approach. We should be able to easily copy, paste and run that code without any substantial modifications, so that we can actually focus on the problem without being distracted by trying to reproduce it.

Comment: I will edit my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

The most important is that you're trying to mimic the behavior of uic generated files, and you're also doing it in the wrong way.
Those files are intended to be left *unmodified* their classes should not ever be subclassed (unless you really, **really** know what you're doing).

The culprit is this line:

```py
self.ui.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

You're setting the delegate on the `ui` object, but that object is **never** used within the UI: the classes generated by uic are only used to *set up* the UI, they are just common interfaces that also happen to be classes in order to allow multiple inheritance. They are not intended to be used for direct inheritance, they should only be used either for composition *or* with multiple inheritance.

The table you're actually using is the `tableView` attribute of `self.ui`, so that line should be the following:

```py
self.ui.tableView.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Unless you're actually basing your program on a UI file created in Designer, there's absolutely no point in creating such "form classes". Just inherit your *main* class(es) from a QWidget subclass and build the UI around it.

In any case, trying to make those classes inherit from Qt widget classes is pointless as it is wrong.

---

Then, since you only need to draw *over* the default painting, you don't need to do everything on your own. Just call the default `paint()` implementation and *then* draw the line.

In your latest modification the model doesn't have any named reference for the first column as in your original post, so I'm just providing an example based on the current data: I'm going to assume that we only want to draw a line whenever the first column has 5 as its value:

```py
class TickerTableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
        if index.column() > 0:
            reference = index.siblingAtColumn(0)
        else:
            reference = index
        if reference.data() == 5:
            painter.drawLine(
                option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight())
```

Note that the parent argument you used for the delegate constructor is also invalid. The common convention is to set it to the view that will actually use it, and, considering the above note, using `self.ui` is wrong; it should be created like this:

```py
self.delegate = TickerTableDelegate(self.ui.tableView)
```

Finally, it's important to be aware about pros and cons of providing sorting or filtering within a model. While supporting sorting in a model is completely valid, it should be done only whenever the implementation actually provides benefits (most importantly, performance-wise). Filtering is a completely different matter: unless done with *extreme* awareness about model and view interactions, trying to achieve it in a basic QAbstractItemModel is usually a perfect recipe for headaches.
In both cases, you should at least consider using a QSortFilterProxyModel set on top of your basic one.

In a case like yours, it would just be a matter of doing the following:

```py
class TickerTableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TickerTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = TickerTableView()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.tableModel = TickerTableModel()
        self.tableModel.setupModel(data)

        self.proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.tableModel)

        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
```

The above will *automatically* provide proper sorting when clicking the headers, and setting a filter would just be a matter of calling the related functions (such as [`setFilterRegExp()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterRegExp-prop)) or eventually implementing [`filterAcceptsRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow).

Comment: for the delegate how would I highlight a specific column. `option.rect` only has button right and left. not side.

Comment: I want to say if the column is in the last column, set the border to have side lines.

Comment: I assume that by "button" you meant "bottom". `option.rect` is a [QRect](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrect.html), I drew the bottom "side" using the `bottomLeft()` and `bottomRight()` *corners*, if you want the *left* and *right* side you need to combine those with `topLeft()` and `topRight()`.

Comment: thanks, so I drew from the bottomLeft to the topLeft and bottomRIght to topRIght to put the column in vertical lines. Now, I just need to figure out how to select the last column.

Comment: You could check if the index column is the last of the model in the delegate: `index.column() == index.model().columnCount() - 1`.

Comment: And I set the thickness with `painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.black, 5))`. I think that about covers the angles for this question, thanks! I have some questions on the adding tabs like chrome question if you would not mind!

Comment: hey @musicamante, I add a new tab on a button click. That tab has buttons that create the populate the page with widgets. I want to be able to delete the tab as well (which I am stumbling with). Can you help me out?

Comment: @DavidFrick Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a forum, and comments should avoid going off topic from the main subject of the question. If you have an issue with a specific and limited aspect of a given answer, then comment there, assuming that the problem may require a simple explanation, is closely related to the issue *and* won't probably require an extended answer. Otherwise, create a new post.